# WebView inside listview is giving jerky behaviour while scrolling

Tags: android-listview, android-webview

I am showing some html feed in my application using Webview as ListItem 
    and it works great except that it is very sluggish at times. Since I 
    don't know the size of the content then I can't set the height of each 
    Webview and therefore I have the following code (this is the code for 
    a single ListItem):

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/rss_title" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        style="@style/RssText" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

But the "wrap_content" causes the Webview to readjust size when 
scrolling. The scrollbar-indicator of the listview also has problems 
knowing the size of the complete list so it changes size when 
scrolling. All this causes a very "jerky" experience when scrolling.

Is there any better way of doing this? Would really appreciate any 
help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this settings on `WebView`

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
settings.setTextSize(TextSize.LARGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading complex HTML (or stuff from the web) I suggest you just have a fixed size WebView and display everything in it. Whatever UI you have in mind for that Fragment/Activity/View, do it in HTML.

Getting WebView working correctly for all cases with a scrollable parent container is really hard. Not only do you have to deal with the content loading asynchronously (so the size changes like you mentioned), you also need to put in tons of hacks for the WebView to scroll correctly (I bet your solution doesn't allow divs/iframes to scroll in the WebView) and getting fixed position elements behaving correctly is also an issue. Plus remember to test KK and JB as the WebViews there differ significantly.